# kendoui scheduler - prevent server calls during the navigate event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

i need to prevent server calls that are automatically triggered during the `navigate` event of the scheduler, because i need to call a my function `LoadData` that does a lot of things and then permfors a server call `datasource.read()` programmatically

The scheduler is configired with the `weekTimeline view`

i've tried in this way

```
navigate: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //<<--this block all
                               

        LoadData() //<-- this perform a server call but before try to read the current scheduer view dates (that are not "updated" (are the old ones) because "e.preventDefault()" has blocked the movement from a week to the next 

}
```

This prevents the server call but prevents the date navigation as well (doesn't move on the next week

is it possible to block the server call **only** and continue to do everithing is normally done with the scheduler during this event?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`navigate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/events/navigate) event provides the following event data:

- e.action
- e.date - Selected date
- e.view
- e.preventDefault - If invoked, prevents the action.
- e.sender - kendo.ui.Scheduler

So you could try and use use the [`date`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/methods/date) method to navigate to the date the user was attempting to navigate in the first place:

```
      navigate:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var scheduler = e.sender;
        var navigateToDate = e.date;

        LoadData()
        //navigate to date
        scheduler.date(navigateToDate);
      }
```

Comment: it seems a smart trick.. but `scheduler.date(navigateToDate);` perform a server call. I'd like call the server only in my `LoadData` function where i'm going to read the new dates before to call the server

Comment: By default the Scheduler will fetch all the records, so do yo have some sort of server filtering, like [this](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/html-helpers/scheduling/scheduler/server-filtering)? If that's the case, than a bit hacky approach would be to not prevent the navigate event, but rather use a global variable to prevent the dataSource `requestStart` event when navigating, but enable the request when calling the `dataSource.read` method, [for example](https://dojo.telerik.com/eVACIRUs).

Comment: Is it possible in some way, instead of defining a global condition, "to infer" wich event triggered the call? in Devtools(F12) there is an "initiator" panel that shows an incomprehensible call stack. Does exist a method in javascritpt to understand what event (in my case "navigate" event) has generated the call?

Comment: The navigate event fires when the user navigates to prev/next day, clicks Toady button, changes the selected date from the calendar, the selected view or switches between full day and business hours. What I could come up with is to check the `event.currentTarget` for details on whether any of these DOM elements were clicked and if so to prevent the requestStart event - https://dojo.telerik.com/AXAjISun